# Дамп базы postgres по ssh

Tags: postgresql, docker

Есть удаленный сервер, подключаюсь по ssh `ssh [username]@[host] -p [port]` далее перехожу в контейнер `ssh [containerName]` где создаю дамп базы через pg_dump дамп сохраняется в этом контейнере, как я могу его скопировать к себе на ПК?

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего переслать с контейнера на свой хост, если на контейнере есть интернет.
Если нет такой возможности, можно попробовать пробросить порт до контейнера, в первом терминале запустить:`ssh -L 127.0.0.1:33333:containerName:22 username@host -pPort`, во втором терминале `scp -P 33333 userContainer@127.0.0.1:/pathContainer/file ./` -но я так не пробовал, только в теории.